# Indexing elements in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to take the indices of each element in the list `a=[2,4,5,2]`
when I enter  `a.index(2)` I get 0 as output. How can I take the index of the fourth element like that way in Python?

Comment: `a.index(2)` returns the index of the first `2` in `a`. Did you mean you want to access the element `4` (different from the fourth element)? That would simply be `a[1]` (python indexing starts at 0). Also  try `[(i, x) in enumerate(a)]`.

Comment: Well, there are 2 twos, so it gets the first one

Comment: `index()` only gets the index of the first occurrence. Do you want all the indexes for each item?

Answer (score 2):

You could recover all the indices like so

```
indices = [i for i in xrange(len(a)) if a[i] == 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this to get them all:

```
[print i for i,v in enumerate(a) if v==2] # or any number
```

Comment: Why are you calling print (plus this is a Python2 question)?

Comment: Good point. I will change it. However, in Python 2, using parenthesis still works. It just simplifies it like an expression

Answer (score 1):

You could also store the indexes for each item in a [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

a=[2,4,5,2]

indexes = defaultdict(list)
for i, e in enumerate(a):
    indexes[e].append(i)

print(indexes)
```

Which gives:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {2: [0, 3], 4: [1], 5: [2]})
```

Then you could access the indexes for each item like this:

```
>>> indexes[2]
[0, 3]
>>> for i in indexes[2]:
...     print(i, '-->', a[i])
... 
0 --> 2
3 --> 2
```

Or as @Idlehands pointed out in the comments, you can use [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) here:

```
indexes = {}
for i, e in enumerate(a):
    indexes.setdefault(e, []).append(i)

print(indexes)
```

Which also gives:

```
{2: [0, 3], 4: [1], 5: [2]}
```

Comment: You can also do this with the `built-in dict`.  `indexes.setdefault(e, list()).append(i)` would work just the same.

Comment: @Idlehands Yep that would work just as great. Even more efficient: `indexes.setdefault(e, []).append(i)`. I believe using `[]` is less costly than `list()`, I could be mistaken though.